# DatePicker in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, datepicker

I know similar and identical questions have been asked before but none have gotten the answer I need.

I have a form where users enter a date. Obviously it is better for the UX that they have a calendar or similar easy way of picking the date for something. However, Firefox does not support the date picker input type offered by Chrome and Safari.

Because I want my application to be as light-weight and easy to load as possible, I do not want to use JQuery UI. I am using JQuery for many other things so that is a possibility. I want something that matches the GUI of Firefox and does not inhibit the date picker of other browsers that do support the input type.

If this is not possible, is there anyway to make sure that the date is formulated similar to how Chrome formulates it's dates or to in some other way make it easier for the user to enter the date? Preferably with JavaScript or HTML examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use jQuery UI, you can use something else like https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday - it's lightweight and certainly better than jQuery UI one in my opinion.

In order to be consistent with the formatting, you could disable Chrome's native date picker (and Safari) and instead consistently use the same date picker across your application for similar UX.